# The command "composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf" always gets an error

Tags: php, laravel, caching, composer-php, dompdf

I am trying to run this command: `composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

And I get this in my cmd:

```
Using version ^1.0 for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (v1.0.0)
  - Locking dompdf/dompdf (v1.2.2)
  - Locking phenx/php-font-lib (0.5.4)
  - Locking phenx/php-svg-lib (0.4.1)
  - Locking sabberworm/php-css-parser (8.4.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing sabberworm/php-css-parser (8.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing phenx/php-svg-lib (0.4.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing phenx/php-font-lib (0.5.4): Extracting archive
  - Installing dompdf/dompdf (v1.2.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (v1.0.0): Extracting archive
3 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
Generating optimized autoload files
Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
@php artisan package:discover --ansi

In PackageManifest.php line 178:

  The C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\Monitor\bootstrap\cache directory must be present and writable.


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

And even on top of that, my project stopped working and shows:

This error that I've never seen before
[image: This error that I´ve ever seen before]

I tried everything that I found on internet, clear cache, update composer and still I get the same kind of error, I am using Laravel 9 version. I'm desperate please help

Comment: So, is your `bootstrap\cache directory` present and writable? (The error suggests it is not)

Comment: Yes, im using windows so I cannot use "sudo chmod 777" but i see the configuration and it is writeable

Comment: Windows has other means to set permissions on a file/folder, rightclick -> properties somewhere iirc

Comment: I have all permisions to this folder (I cant upload a screenshot)

Comment: And I have a question. It isnt bad to have a 777 folder in a public website?

Comment: `bootstrap/cache` isn't publicly available, it's outside of the `public` folder. Ideally you'd give the user that is running the webserver write permissions to that folder, not everyone

Comment: Then i give all permissions to all users in my laptop and still it says it is not writeable

Comment: Deleting the cache-dir and remaking it - or delete the bootstrap directory - but save the app.php first - and remake the structure.

Comment: 775 permission is always idle.

Comment: Make sure you apply the permissions to the `cache` folder and its subfolders too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 : Delete the `cache` folder and recreate again in `bootstrap` directory.

step 2 : run the command `php artisan cache:clear`